# Свой шаблон для всех подкатегорий одной рубрики wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У основной рубрики *услуги* есть свой шаблон category-uslugi.php

У этой рубрики очень много подрубрик. Как всем этим подрубрикам именно этой категории *услуги* сделать свой шаблон, который отличается от основных шаблонов category-uslugi.php и category.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверяем id родительской категории в category.php и подключаем нужный нам шаблон

```
  if ( get_queried_object()->parent == '12' ) {
      get_template_part( 'templates/archive', 'service' );
    } else {
      get_template_part( 'templates/archive', 'common' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как всем этим подрубрикам именно этой категории услуги сделать свой
> шаблон, который отличается от основных шаблонов category-uslugi.php и
> category.php?

Можно в `category-uslugi.php` (или `category.php`) сделав проверку на соответствие наличия подрубрик (с пом [get_term_parents_list()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term_parents_list)) подключать произвольный шаблон с пом. [load_template()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/load_template)

Или можно использовать [get_template_part()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part)

Comment: ничего непонятно, но очень интересно) а можно пример кода? пожалуйста.

Comment: @Olegzyuzin по ссылкам есть и описание работы функций и варианты применения  . Что именно не понятно?